# Problemas mostrando tildes y ñ en recyclerview desde base de datos externa

Tags: android, recyclerview

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas tardes a todos. 
La cuestión es sobre cómo mostrar las tildes y ñ desde la base de datos externa que fue integrada a un proyecto Android.

La base de datos se infla en un recyclerview pero la información con tildes se convierte en símbolos (tal como se muestra en la imagen adjunta)
Agradezco si pueden brindarme su ayuda. 
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Muy probablemente no estés configurando bien el juego de caracteres en el objeto que usas para conectar a la base de datos (en el servidor). Para evitar este tipo de problemas, usa el charset `utf8` en todas partes: conexión, encabezados, tablas y columnas de la base de datos. Usa también `header` con un charset  `utf8`, sea que los datos se reciban como JSON o como HTML. Sugiero que [revises esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967), para más detalles.

Answer (score 0):

creo que esto tiene que ver entre la codificación de la base de datos y la que tiene tu página.

Me explico, cuando uno crea una base de datos te pregunta qué cotejamiento va a tener utf8-unicode-ci ... hay muchos, y por otra parte tienes la codificación de tu página web que siempre se ve en el tag meta charset.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Fijate cual tienes en tu página, quizás sea cosa de cambiarla para que pueda mostrar bien esa nueva simbología que dices. puedes probar con:

```
<meta charset=ISO-8859-1″ />
```

Te dejo un link para que puedas ver los caracteres especiales y como arreglarlo: [Caracteres especiales en html](http://blog.fidelizador.com/2017/09/27/utf8-n-tildes-y-caracteres-especiales/)

Saludos